# Find users who tends to be together with machinelearning

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've a CSV file with lots of users ids and a timestamp when they were present. I want to use machine learning to find users who tends to visit together. By looking at my example of the CSV file, you can see that `user1` and `user2` visited, at around same time, and same with `user3` and `user4` While `user5` and `user6` visited individually. Note that users can appear multiple times in the dataset, one new record is added for each time they visit.

```
user1,2017-08-06 08:00:30
user2,2017-08-06 08:00:35
user3,2017-08-07 12:00:10
user4,2017-08-07 12:00:15
user5,2017-08-08 07:00:00
user6,2017-08-08 20:00:00
...
```

So fare I managed to plot each record on a 3D scatter plot, but I actually just want one point for each user, and have those who visit at the same time to be close to each other. Also giving each user a unique color on the graph. I tried the normal array approach instead of Numpy since, I had lots of problems working it out. Are there a more simple and straight forward way to handle the dataset, then I did in my code below. Also how do I make only one point for each user, with a unique color?

So fare I've come up with this code

```
data = [] # array with all data
with open('data/data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

    #Read csv file
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 

    #Loop each line/row
    for row in readCSV:

        # Convert string to datetime
        fulldate = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
        name = row[0] 
        year   = fulldate.year
        month  = fulldate.month
        day    = fulldate.day
        hour   = fulldate.hour
        minute = fulldate.minute

        data.append([year, month, day, hour, minute])



model = TSNE(n_components=3, perplexity=20, early_exaggeration=4.0, learning_rate=10000, n_iter=1000,
            n_iter_without_progress=50, min_grad_norm=0, init='pca', method='exact', verbose=2)

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

tsne_array = model.fit_transform(data)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


for element in tsne_array:
    ax.scatter(element[0], element[1],element[2], color="r")

pyplot.show()
```

The TSNE hyperparameters are just some that I've found, haven't adjusted them myself.

Comment: this sounds more like a graph question if the ml side works... maybe look into force directed graphs for visualizing user relationships. If you want other directions, take a look at clustering the users by time... but I don't think you even need ml to see who arrives at similar times.

Comment: Well before I can make a graph that makes sense from higher dimensional datasets, don't i need to use some kind of dimensional reduction(not sure if you call this machinelearning, maybe not)? I've looked into force directed graphs, but I can see how it can be implemented since the timestamps can vary in multiple ways.

Comment: you only wanted to visualize how close the users arrive by time, right? Create some sort of scoring for how similar the arrival times are, then use that for the graph. You don't really need to display the raw time data.